# How does a reference clock "drive" a VCO

Tags: embedded, clock

Reading the following chapter:
[https://users.ece.utexas.edu/~valvano/Volume1/E-Book/C10_FiniteStateMachines.htm](https://users.ece.utexas.edu/%7Evalvano/Volume1/E-Book/C10_FiniteStateMachines.htm)

In the beginning, on top of Figure 10.1, the author claims that:

> Because the reference clock is stable, the feedback loop in the PLL will drive the output to a stable 400 MHz frequency.

Question: How does a 16MHz clock drive a 400MHz PLL? (I checked the wiki for PLL but didn't understand much)

A bit of background: I don't know much about electronics, and apparently this book doesn't really require students to understand such questions (it focuses on writing C programs for an eval board). I'm just curious.

Comment: Simply put: a PLL is a circuit that changes a frequency to another frequency. This is actually a hardware question so it is off-topic here and should be asked at https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frequency_multiplier?wprov=sfla1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In simple words: A PLL works by "comparing" the reference frequency with its own frequency. If its frequency is too low, it raises it a bit, and if it's too high, it lowers it a bit. This is what the feedback loop does. (Actually, the *phase* is used for comparison. That's why it's called a ["phase lock[ed] loop"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phase-locked_loop).)

So your question boils down to: How can a frequency of 400 MHz be compared with a frequency of 16 MHz?

Well, as such, it cannot. For the comparison in the "Phase/Freq Detector" both frequencies need to be nearly the same. "Nearly" because while not being locked, the VCO's frequency might be "off track".

The solution is to divide the 400 MHz down to 16 MHz, by the value of 25. This is what the block "/m" in the linked page does:

[image: PLL]

The "programming" aspect in your question: You set up the divisor by choosing the right `XTAL` from the table.

After division, the detector receives two frequencies in the same range.